# Custom Admin Template doesn't seem to be working

Tags: admin, layout, adminhtml, template

I want to be able to use a custom template on the backend of Magento also known as the Admin Panel.  I have Magento 1.7!

In my controller:
**app/code/local/Sean/AdminMerchant/controllers/AdminMerchantController.php**

```
<?php
class Sean_AdminMerchant_AdminMerchantController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction(){
        echo $this->getFullActionName();
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

^When I echo out getFullActionName() I receive adminhtml_adminMerchant_index

Which shows that it's getting to the controller!

**app/code/local/Sean/AdminMerchant/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sean_AdminMerchant>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sean_AdminMerchant>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <sean_adminmerchant>
                <class>Sean_AdminMerchant_Helper</class>
            </sean_adminmerchant>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Sean_AdminMerchant after="Mage_Adminhtml">Sean_AdminMerchant</Sean_AdminMerchant>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <sean_adminmerchant>
                    <file>adminmerchant.xml</file>
                </sean_adminmerchant>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/adminmerchant.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_adminMerchant_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="sean" template="adminmerchant/merchant.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_adminMerchant_index>
</layout>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/adminmerchant/merchant.phtml**

```
<p>Hey guys! I want this to show up!</p>
```

I have a feeling that there is a capital letter somewhere throwing something off.  Maybe your eyes could show me anything you see wrong!  Keep in mind my module is called AdminMerchant the M is capitalized.

Comment: It's unusual to use `adminhtml` as handle for a custom module. Nevertheless, it should work. Having said that, there are some inconsistencies in your _config.xml_. In `<helpers>` you have `<sean_adminmerchant>`, but in `<updates>`, it's `<adminmerchant>`. It's best to settle on one and use it throughout. According to your _config.xml_ *as it is* without chnages, try changing your controller to `Mage_Adminhtml_AdminMerchantController` and save to **app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AdminMerchantController.php**. That is what is defined in layout `<adminhtml_adminMerchant_index>`.

Comment: I can try changing the controller but would that cause a problem even if it's getting there? Cause if I do die("hello there") inside the indexAction of the controller it hits it already.

Comment: also im unsure as to what you're saying for config.xml.  I have sean_adminmerchant for both helpers and updates already.